Two sequences with limit properties
Do there exist sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$ defined for all positive integers $n$ such that:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n \neq \lim_{n \to \infty} b_n;$$
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} (a_n - b_n) = 0;$$ and
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} (a_n / b_n) \neq 1?$$
I was considering $a_n = \sin(n) + \frac{1}{n}; b_n = \sin(n)$, but I couldn't prove that its ratio didn't go to 1.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

First two conditions can only hold if neither the $a_n$ nor the $b_n$ have a limit. If either does, together with $a_n-b_n\to 0$ give that they both exist and have equal limit.

I'm trying to find any $a_n$ or $b_n$ that work, even if they don't have a limit; I think they have to oscillate or else (if they go to infinity) either $a_n / b_n \to 1$ or $a_n - b_n$ doesn't go to $0$.

@Mathslover please don't post comments that are not related with the question posted by the OP.

You recieved 3 answers to your question. Is any of them what you needed? If so, consider accepting the best answer and upvoting all useful answers you got. That's how the site works.

First, notice that
$$\frac{a_n}{b_n} = \frac{b_n + (a_n - b_n)}{b_n} = 1 + \frac{a_n - b_n}{b_n}.$$
Now, we have the condition that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n-b_n) = 0$$ which means $a_n-b_n$ can be arbitrarily small. This means that when looking for a counterexample, you will need a sequence where $b_n$ also becomes arbitrarily small infinitely many times.
At the same time, $a_n$ and $b_n$ must both be divergent sequences, because otherwise if one is convergent, then so is the other and their limit will be equal.
So perhaps something like
$$a_n = 1, \frac12, 1, \frac13,1,\frac14,\dots , 1,\frac 1n,1,\dots$$
and $$b_n = 1,\frac14,1,\frac19,1,\frac1{16},\dots,1,\frac1{n^2},1,\dots$$
would work. In that case, you have
$$\frac{a_n}{b_n} = 1,2,1,3,1,4,1,5,\dots$$ so this limit is not equal to $1$ (since it doesn't exist).
At the same time, you have $$|a_n - b_n| < \frac1n - \frac{1}{n^2} \to 0$$
so the limit $$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n-b_n$$ exists and is equal to $0$.

Essentially, we want a sequence $x_n$ that converges to $0$, and a sequence $y_n$ that does not converge. Then taking $a_n=x_n+y_n$ and $b_n=y_n$, we get sequences that satisfy your first two conditions. The tricky part is ensuring the third.
I was thinking along the same lines as 5xum: if we have $a_n$ and $b_n$ as above, then the third condition amounts to requiring that $\frac{x_n}{y_n}$ does not approach $0$. Since the $x_n$ do approach zero, that means that the $y_n$ cannot be bounded away from $0$ (for if $|y_n|\gt M$ for some $M$, then $\left|\frac{x_n}{y_n}\right|\lt\frac{|x_n|}{M}$, and since the latter converge to $0$, so would the former); so we're going to need a subsequence of the $y_n$ that converges to $0$.
For example, take $x_n = \frac{1}{n}$, and let
$$y_n = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
\frac{1}{n}&\text{if }n\text{ is odd}\\
n &\text{if }n\text{ is even.}
\end{array}\right.$$
Then
$$a_n = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
\frac{2}{n} &\text{if }n\text{ is odd}\\
\frac{n^2+1}{n}&\text{if }n\text{ is even}.
\end{array}\right.\qquad\text{and}\qquad b_n = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
\frac{1}{n}&\text{if }n\text{ is odd}\\
n &\text{if }n\text{ is even.}
\end{array}\right.$$
Then $\lim a_n$ and $\lim b_n$ do not exist, and in particular are not equal. $a_n-b_n = \frac{1}{n}$, so $\lim(a_n-b_n)=0$.
And $$\frac{a_n}{b_n} = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
2&\text{if }n\text{ is odd},\\
\frac{n^2+1}{n^2}&\text{if }n\text{ is even.}
\end{array}\right.$$
Note that the subsequence of odd terms of $\frac{a_n}{b_n}$ converges to $2$, whereas the subsequence of even terms converges to $1$. Thus, $\frac{a_n}{b_n}$ does not converge, and in particular the limit is not $1$.

Your first two conditions directly contradict a fundamental property of limits, specifically the alegebra of limits. Moreover the 3rd condition is a constradiction as well assuming $M \neq 0$. For two sequences that have a definite limit, say $a_n \rightarrow L$ and $b_n \rightarrow M$, as $n\rightarrow \infty$, alegebra of limits tells us that:
$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty } (a_n +b_n) = L + M$
Proofs of this thereom result are readily available online.

So, as I noted, what the conditions imply is that neither $a_n$ nor $b_n$ have a limit. This is not a contradiction. Two sequences without a limit may have a difference that does have a limit.

@ArturoMagidin, I see. Thanks for the clarification. Based on first reading of your question you don't imply that they don't have a limit, you simply state there limits are not equal. I assumed they both had limits that exisited.

It's not my question.
